# Is it possible to write a function pow(T number,T exponent), T being a numeric type in C#?

Tags: c#, numeric

### What I mean is:

- is it possible to have a generic numeric function in C# aiming to avoid the use of overloads for different numeric types such int, byte, double, float,...,vectors of int, ... , matrixes of complex numbers, weird never-seen-before structures that behave like numbers for some reason ecc..?
- if not C# is there a language which can handle these kind of problems in a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. Not without rewriting the framework. There is NO common ground between the numberic structs to use.

Comment: I've seen an approach that might work, Related posts are based on C# 4.0 which is now aged almost 4-6 years. I just want to make sure that nothing has changed nor improved to start new with a cutting-edge approach